# Struggling with "Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?" issue

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-sdk-tools

[image: The issue I dislike a lot.]So I'm trying to resolve this issue for most of today... What ever device/resolution/anything I choose it's displayed incorrectly, and looks like styles aren't loading...

> ***Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?***
>
> *Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.
>   Couldn't find theme resource  for the current theme*

I tried:

- re-downloading & re-installing ADT
- same with eclipse plugin
- tried almost every combination of options in drop-down lists - none of them worked
- tried re-adding project (from disk, from remote repository)
- changing target in AndroidManifest.xml and in project properties
- cleaning, building, running, anything that came to my mind or I could find on stackoverflow
- restarting my computer (yes, 3 times), and eclipse
- running it on other project, and **sometimes it works fine there**!

I'm running on:

- Elementary OS (Ubuntu based) - Linux maurycy-EOS **3.2.0-35-generic** #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:42:16 UTC 2012 **x86_64** x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Eclipse **4.2.1**
- Android SDK Tools **21.1 rc1** (yes, it's a preview, but it's not working on **21.0.1** too)
- Android SDK Platform-tools **16.0.1**
- java version "**1.7.0_09**"; OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.3) (7u9-2.3.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1); OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

**If anyone had similar issue, have any clue what might've caused that, or can help in any possible way, I'd be really glad to hear from you!**

It kinda looks like there's no styles installed on my machine :|

If you think there's something wrong with my code, here it is: http://goo.gl/bbVdc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So turns out my problem was in my code. My problem was that I've been setting **question mark** alone as a content of the string. And, as I was told, question mark is also the character which starts a theme reference.

Other words, my problem was caused by [android bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39612).

### edit:

It's worth noting that this bug has been fixed since then, so if you're still having this problem try **updating your adt**.